# understanding channel in java.nio package

Tags: java, io, buffer, nio

For direct mapped buffer, they always stay outside jvm heap. Channels, on the other hand, seem to also exists in the IO operation. I'm just wondering if a the corresponding channel for the direct mapped buffer also stays outside jvm heap?

Also, The other question comes from the necessity of existence of Channel in terms of memory operation efficiency. I understand that

> A channel represents an open connection to an entity such as a hardware device

Yet, in the situation of writing to file through the direct mapped buffer, is the contents being written twice? The content is first written to the buffer then to the channel. Would this be low efficiency versus "directly" writing to the IO device?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think I figure out the answer.

Direct mapped buffer first write to a buffer, which is non IO operation. The IO operation for real write that updates the file happens afterwards. The reason for two write is that since we have DMA, we don't want all IO operation happen by times. All IO operation in one time is more efficient.

Getting the starting address through the JNI is not correct address for accessing that piece of memory. Instead, the address for data is a field is hidden in java.nio.buffer. One way to get this field is though sun.misc.Unsafe in making the field public.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm just wondering if a the corresponding channel for the direct mapped buffer also stays outside jvm heap?

The question doesn't make sense. A Channel isn't a piece of memory, it is an interface to an operating system FD.

> in the situation of writing to file through the direct mapped buffer, is the contents being written twice? The content is first written to the buffer then to the channel. Would this be low efficiency versus "directly" writing to the IO device?

No. The `MappedByteBuffer` is independent of the channel it came from. For example, it isn't closed when the channel is closed.

Are you perhaps looking for direct *byte* buffers? They do exist, and you write to them via channels, but I/O via them happens once, not twice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Say I'm doing a write to a file. Does this mean that it first does a non-IO write to buffer, then IO write to the real file through channel?

Comment: And for the buffer itself, if I get its starting address from JNI, and knows the object layout in memory (to know offset of real contents). Is it guaranteed that I could actually fetch real file contents from just that starting address+offset?

Comment: @jer_yin You don't seem to have ever written any NIO code. *You* put data into the buffer, then you call `channel.write(buffer).` For reading, you call `channel.read(buffer)`, and then fetch data from the buffer.

Comment: I'm not asking the question for the sake of writing NIO code either.